# How to pass database connection variable to a new page safely?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Hello there you might say this question has already been answered but believe me I have searched them all before asking but am still confused. I am trying to pass database connection variable `$conn` to a function in a new file and I don't want to do it globally as it is not safe. Can you please help me with a solution and a explanation as far as how I can go about this? I like to learn and don't want free code. Here is my code below so far:

Below is the code for connecting to database:

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','my_cms');

function connecting ($conn) {

    $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        die( "Sorry! Can't connect to the database." . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

And here is my code for login function in functions.php file

```
function login($user, $pass)
{  
    $user = $conn->real_escape_string($user);
    $pass = $conn->real_escape_string($pass);
    $password = md5($pass);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password=?");
    $result->bind_param("ss", $user, $password); 
    $result->execute() or die('Query failed. '); 

    if ($result->num_rows) 
    {
         $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
         header('Location: '.DIRADMIN);
         exit();
    } 
    else 
    {
         $_SESSION['error'] = 'Sorry, wrong username or password';
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: `require_once` or use framework

Comment: @Chay22 sorry but require what once you mean the config.php file? I have already done that. also use what framework? Can you be more specific please? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways and design patterns to consider. One simple way to go about this is by defining the database connection functionality in a single file and then including that file in any page that will need to access the database. For example:

In the file `database.inc.php`:

```
<?php
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','my_cms');

$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    die( "Sorry! Can't connect to the database." . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Then for every page that needs the database connection, do the following:

```
<?php
require_once '...\database.inc.php';

function login($conn, $user, $pass)
{  
    $user = $conn->real_escape_string($user);
    $pass = $conn->real_escape_string($pass);
    $password = md5($pass);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password); 
    $stmt->execute() or die('Query failed. ');
    ....
}
...
?>
```

Comment: What was the error? Did you use the correct file path for the include file?

Comment: well yeah I am using Microsoft Expression and it has this insert option that inserts the require_once code by itself. and then here is the error:




Warning: Missing argument 3 for login(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\login.php on line 18 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\functions.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\functions.php on line 8

Comment: Did you modify your `login()` function to accept 3 arguments as shown in the example above? Your original function has 2 (username, password).

Comment: @Chay22 nice catch. @mrRay, try renaming the variables `$sql` and `$result` to `$stmt` (by convention). See updated answer.

Comment: @reformed well, Actually when I press undo on Microsoft Expression it does undoes several steps back and this might be the old version but even when I had $sql for execute and all, I still get an error. The problem is, its not recognizing the $conn variable which is the connection variable but it does if I put globally in the login function. but thats not safe with OOP php. So my question is how would I use Dependency Injection here?

Comment: There are several other issues going on here with your code as well. When you get a chance, research PHP's PDO prepared statements, password hashing and database storage.

Comment: You would be using dependency injection by passing in the `$conn` object as an argument to your `login()` function.

Comment: @reformed when you said there are other issues can you please point out what problems do you see here? thanks.

Comment: @mrRay though you can get the code above to work, there are better ways of going about it. For one, you should be using a different hashing method than MD5. What you're doing is performing a SELECT statement based on the username and MD5 hashed password. A better approach would be to retrieve the username and password and perform the hashing in PHP, instead, using PHP's built in functions (PHP 5.5+) such as `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: Also, if you're already using a prepared statement with parameters (e.g., `bind_param()`, you don't have to use the `real_escape_string` method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, you could chose to use [PHP Session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) .  It's not clear why using a global for something like this is specifically unsafe, either.